# Delay with Bluetooth headphones

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

With every pair of Bluetooth headphones I've owned I've had a latency of about 50 ms.

**How do I get rid of or reduce this delay?**

MacBook Pro with Retina, Mid 2015, macOS Mojave 10.14.3 (but I had the problem on earlier OSes).

Comment: Have you tested the Bluetooth headphones on other devices besides the MacBook Pro and experience the same latency?

Comment: @user3439894 I get the same latency. I guess it's a bluetooth problem. Why is bluetooth so slow though that doesn't make any sense